# Add a jQuery Function to a dynamically generated Control (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I create a Control (Dynamically):
Example:

```
Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.Id = "button1";
```

.. and so far..

So, but now, how do I add this Button a jquery Function?

Something like this didn't work for me:

```
$("#button1").live('click', function () {
alert("hi iam getting dynamic added button");});
```

What can I do? Hope u guys can help me :(

Comment: Is your button dynamically created during `Page_Load` or a later event?

Comment: yes, the Button is created in page_load or in Page_init, but it dont works.. I think, cause the button is regenerating always :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a generic js function that takes the Id of the control which has been clicked

```
function ShowMessage(){
   alert("hi iam getting dynamic added button");
}
```

then on the server side

```
myButton.OnClientClick = "ShowMessage()";
```

if you don't want raise a post back:

```
myButton.OnClientClick = "ShowMessage();return false";
```

Comment: thx 4 answer, but this wont work too, because I create the button in Page_Load, so I click him, nothing happens - the page reloads (postback)

Comment: ok, this worked : myButton.OnClientClick = "ShowMessage();return false";
thx :D

Answer (score 0):

```
myButton.OnClientClick = "clientFunction()";
```

On client side:

```
function clientFunction() {
}
```

Comment: thx 4 answer, but this wont work too, because I create the button in Page_Load, so I click him, nothing happens - the page reloads (postback)

Answer (score 0):

I believe when the page is rendered to the client, `button1` will be changed to a rendered ID. I think it would be better adding a class to the button, and assigning jQuery events to that:

C#:

```
Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.Id = "button1";
myButton.CssClass = myButton.Id;
```

Javascript:

```
$(".button1").live('click', function () {
alert("hi iam getting dynamic added button");});
```

Comment: thx 4 answer, yaa good idea, but wouldnt work cause Postback.. and anyway I cant use this, cause I will create about 100 Buttons, so they have different Id's, and on each Button there should be a different event :D

Comment: Why would PostBack effect it? See changes to answer regarding the class being different everytime